# why setSelection doesn't work in ComboViewer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a combo, with a comboViewer in Jface,
and because is an update record dialog, I wan to sel the combo with correct selection.

I'm tryin to use

```
//Seleccionar Protocolo
    if (fcruza.getTipoCosecha() != null)
        comboProtocoloViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(fcruza.getTipoCosecha()));
```

But the combo is not selected.

I follow java code, but I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Also I have this on this control:

```
    comboProtocoloViewer = new ComboViewer(comboProtocolo);
    comboProtocoloViewer.setContentProvider (new ArrayContentProvider());
    comboProtocoloViewer.setLabelProvider (new ProtocoloLabelProvider());  

    comboProtocoloViewer.setInput(tipoCosechaController.obtenerTipoCosecha());
```

Any sugestion.
Best regards

Comment: Are you sure fcruza.getTipoCosecha() is part of the input (tipoCosechaController.obtenerTipoCosecha())? Debug tipoCosechaController.obtenerTipoCosecha().indexOf(fcruza.getTipoCosecha());

Comment: And you could try to call comboProtocoloViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(tipoCosechaController.obtenerTipoCosecha().get(1))); Assuming that tipoCosechaController.obtenerTipoCosecha() is a list and has at least 2 elements in it.

Comment: Hi, tipoCosechaController.obtenerTipoCosecha() return this: List<TipoCosecha>, is ok with ArrayContentProvider () ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes `ArrayContentProvider` works with lists. Have you tried selecting an element as I posted earlier? 
You have to make sure the element you are trying to select is part of the list, `equals()` of the element (`fcruza.getTipoCosecha()`) needs to match one of the input list.